# Redirect Custom Post Type after user submits update

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect

I have a function for a custom post type that redirects NEW posts to a specific url after they are submitted by users:

```
function tribe_redirect_after_community_submission( $wp ) {
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] )
    && $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] == 'ce-add-route'
    && !empty( $_POST ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url('http://www.example.com'));
        exit();
    }
}
```

I want to expand upon this so that when a user UPDATES a post, the user gets redirected to a different url.

So just as I'm testing to see if `$wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR]` is set to `ce-add-route`, I need to test against the possibility that it might be set to `ce-edit-route`.

How can I edit my function above to achieve that? I'm a novice with php and didn't write the function on my own.

UPDATE: I revised my function and have the `ce-edit-route` redirect working, however, the `ce-add-route` redirect is no longer working.

```
function tribe_redirect_after_community_submission( $wp ) {
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] )
        && $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] == 'ce-add-route'
        && !empty( $_POST ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url('http://www.example.com/wptest/event-submitted/'));}
    elseif ( isset( $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] )
        && $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] == 'ce-edit-route'
        && !empty( $_POST ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url('http://www.example.com/wptest/event-updated/'));
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed for both redirects to work correctly:

```
function tribe_redirect_after_community_submission( $wp ) {
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] ) 
&& $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] == 'ce-add-route' 
&& !empty( $_POST ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url('http://www.myurlhere.com/event-submitted/'));
        exit();
    } elseif ( isset( $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] ) 
&& $wp->query_vars[WP_Router::QUERY_VAR] == 'ce-edit-route' 
&& !empty( $_POST ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url('http://www.myurlhere.com/event-updated/'));
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a plugin I wrote that handles and performs many redirects after Publish/Update. not sure if it's specific for what you're wanting to do, but might suit you in some other scenario(s).

http://crstauf.github.io/And-Then/